# Navigating between UIViewControllers, retaining selected button image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

How would you save a selected button state after you press it? So when you switch between view controllers and come to the original view controller, the button stays pressed, until you press it again...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    addCheck = NO;
    favCheck = NO;
}

- (IBAction)listButton:(id)sender {

    UIImage *removeListImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"removeList.png"];
    UIImage *addListImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addList.png"];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *favoriteviews = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorite_views_key"];

    [defaults setObject:favoriteviews forKey:@"favorite_views_key"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    if (!addCheck) {

        [addList setImage:removeListImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        addCheck = YES;

        [favoriteviews addObject:@"Apple"];
        [favoriteviews addObject:@"Banana"];
        [favoriteviews addObject:@"Celery"];
    }

    else if (addCheck) {
        [addList setImage:addListImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        addCheck = NO;

        [favoriteviews removeObject:@"Apple"];
        [favoriteviews removeObject:@"Banana"];
        [favoriteviews removeObject:@"Celery"];
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest cases, you can set the images for two different states of the control(button in this case).
And check for the states on each tap to change it. For example

```
if(![myButton isSelected]){
    [myButton setSelected:YES];
    // Do your proceedings when the button is selected here
}
else{
   [myButton setSelected:NO];
   // Do your proceedings when the button is unselected here
}
```

And when you set up your button in `viewDidLoad`, just set the button's images for those two states

```
[addList setImage:addListImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addList setImage:removeListImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Alternatively, if you are setting up button in Interface builder, you can set those images for the two states there too.

It would be better add some logic to it to persist some kind of data to set the button's state depending upon that.

Comment: The pressed button works perfectly, the problem I am having is saving. Once I leave the UIViewController I want whatever state the button was in to stay the same after I navigate out of it, and come back to it later. It keeps going back to UIControlStateNormal.